# Lag pandas variable by a year within groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, finance

I'm hoping to create a lagged yearly return variable in Pandas.

So far I've tried:

```
df_ret_lagged = df_ret.set_index(['year', 'cusip'])
df_ret_lagged['yearly_ret_lag'] = df_ret_lagged['year_ret'].shift(12)
df_ret_lagged.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

However, this just shifts the yearly return down by 12 rows, rather than grouping by *year*. The dataframe below shows what the code has done.

```
    year    cusip        date       year_ret    yearly_ret_lag
0   1983    000165100   1983-09-01  0.183673    NaN
1   1983    000165100   1983-10-01  0.183673    NaN
2   1983    000165100   1983-11-01  0.183673    NaN
3   1983    000165100   1983-12-01  0.183673    NaN
4   1984    000165100   1984-01-01  -0.482758   NaN
5   1984    000165100   1984-02-01  -0.482758   NaN
6   1984    000165100   1984-03-01  -0.482758   NaN
7   1984    000165100   1984-04-01  -0.482758   NaN
8   1984    000165100   1984-05-01  -0.482758   NaN
9   1984    000165100   1984-06-01  -0.482758   NaN
10  1984    000165100   1984-07-01  -0.482758   NaN
11  1984    000165100   1984-08-01  -0.482758   NaN
12  1984    000165100   1984-09-01  -0.482758   0.183673
13  1984    000165100   1984-10-01  -0.482758   0.183673
14  1984    000165100   1984-11-01  -0.482758   0.183673
15  1984    000165100   1984-12-01  -0.482758   0.183673
16  1985    000165100   1985-01-01  1.700000    -0.482758
17  1985    000165100   1985-02-01  1.700000    -0.482758
18  1985    000165100   1985-03-01  1.700000    -0.482758
19  1985    000165100   1985-04-01  1.700000    -0.482758
```

Ideally, I would like the 1983 *year_ret* to fill through all of the 1984 dates, and so on. Additionally, these would have to be grouped by cusip (a company identifier).

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to do with the cusips exactly?

Comment: Hi... did any of the answers help you out? If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used a for loop:

```
for year in df['year'].unique()[1:]: #list of all the years except the first
    df.loc[df['year'] == year, 'year_ret_lag'] = df.loc[df['year'] == year-1, 'year_ret'].iloc[0]
```

df

```
    year    cusip   date        year_ret    year_ret_lag
0   1983    165100  01/09/1983  0.183673    NaN
1   1983    165100  01/10/1983  0.183673    NaN
2   1983    165100  01/11/1983  0.183673    NaN
3   1983    165100  01/12/1983  0.183673    NaN
4   1984    165100  01/01/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
5   1984    165100  01/02/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
6   1984    165100  01/03/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
7   1984    165100  01/04/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
8   1984    165100  01/05/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
9   1984    165100  01/06/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
10  1984    165100  01/07/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
11  1984    165100  01/08/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
12  1984    165100  01/09/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
13  1984    165100  01/10/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
14  1984    165100  01/11/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
15  1984    165100  01/12/1984  -0.482758   0.183673
16  1985    165100  01/01/1985  1.700000    -0.482758
17  1985    165100  01/02/1985  1.700000    -0.482758
18  1985    165100  01/03/1985  1.700000    -0.482758
19  1985    165100  01/04/1985  1.700000    -0.482758
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are asking for. Note that this relies on the dataframe being properly sorted and structured (e.g., having entries for every month) ahead of time.

This sorts everything by cusip and date before shifting it, and then erases the values that are mismatched between cusips by overwriting them with nans. Then you can use `.fillna(method='bfill')` to get the earlier values in there.

```
df_new = df_ret.sort_values(['cusip','date'])
df_new['yearly_ret_lag'] = df_new['year_ret'].shift(12)
df_new.loc[ (df_new['cusip'] != df_new['cusip'].shift(12)) ,'yearly_ret_lag'] = np.nan
df_new['yearly_ret_lag'] = df_new['yearly_ret_lag'].fillna(method='bfill')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, with no loop, which let you possiblities to have missing month, or to groupby cusid is :

building of the df :

```
dates = pd.date_range("1983-09-01","1985-12-31",freq="1M")
df = pd.DataFrame(index =dates,columns=["Year","cusip","year_ret"])
df['Year'] = df.index
df['Year'] = df['Year'].dt.strftime(date_format='%Y')
df['cusip'] = '01234'
df['year_ret'] =[0.183673,0.183673,0.183673,0.183673,-0.482758,-0.482758,-0.482758,-0.482758,-0.482758,-0.482758,-0.482758,-0.482758,-0.482758,-0.482758,-0.482758,-0.482758,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000,1.700000]
```

And the the code:

```
#### First, condition if year changes
_condition_1 = df.Year != df.Year.shift(1)

#### If condition is True, put the past ret as new
df['lag'] = np.where(_condition_1,df['year_ret'].shift(1),np.nan)

#### Fill the nan, and it's ok
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```